# how to download a range in Google spreadsheet in xlsx format

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I know that the correct term would be `&range=A1:AC10` and `export?format=xlsx` and `&gid=417070` as the following:

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uOHeF2u23A_yrrRL7gghhhbybO8MF8HWSVtvaD4/export?format=xlsx&gid=417070&range=A1:AC10`

But this downloads the whole sheet.

How can I download the specified range in xlsx format?

Comment: Unfortunately, in the case of XLSX format, even when the specific range is included in the query parameter, the whole sheet is downloaded. I thought that this might be the current specification at Google side. I apologize for this. But I think that in your situation, there might be a workaround. But I cannot understand about the detail of your goal. Can I ask you about the method for downloading the XLSX file you expect? By this, when there is a workaround, I would like to propose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could copy the desired range values in a new empty sheet, export that complete sheet containing only the values you want and then delete the sheet again:

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('yourId');
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 1');
 var values = sheet.getRange('A1:AC10').getValues();
 var newSheet = ss.insertSheet();
 newSheet.getRange('A1:AC10').setValues(values);
 var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+ ss.getId() +'/export?'
      + 'exportFormat=xlsx&format=xlsx'
      + '&gid='+newSheet.getSheetId();
 ss.deleteSheet(newSheet);
```